# excel VBA - stop a script that is running by pressing <esc> - without error message

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I have a script in Excel that sometimes can run for too long. 
I need a simple method for the users to interrupt.

Right now the solution is to press the [esc] key than the [end] button.

I was wondering if it is possible, to get rid of this pop up window

[image]

Something like: if [esc] is pressed than a simple `End` (stop all scripts) would do the trick

EDIT3: So finally I found out what the problem was. There was a for loop after the do while, so the for did not stop. To solve this, I inserted a simple if - end function, inside the for loop.

I also accept mrbungle's solution because in his link I found a solution to stop the script without error message by pressing [esc]. Thank you for Your answer.

The working code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim StopCode As Boolean 'Global bool

Sub mysub_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim p As String
Dim lastonline As Object
Dim x: Dim y
Dim actives As String
Dim timeoutc As Variant
actives = ActiveSheet.Name

timeoutc = 0

StopCode = False

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
On Error GoTo ErrH:
DoEvents
For Each c In Sheets(actives).UsedRange.Cells
    If StopCode = True Then
        Exit For
    End If

{The code} 'I have deleted it so it is less confusing now       

next c


ErrH:
     If Err.Number = 18 Then
         Debug.Print "break key hit"
     Else
         Debug.Print "other error: "; Err.Number, Err.Description
     End If
End Sub
```

The userform

```
Option Explicit
Dim StopCode As Boolean 'Global bool

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'close button
PTimeout.Hide 
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'stop script button (does not work)

StopCode = True
PTimeout.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: Usually, you set up the code so it is dynamic, are you using a loop? What does the code look like?

Comment: I use only a for loop that checks every used cell

Comment: right now I have started working on mrbungle's idea, so I will update the code with his Do until method. This does not work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chip Pearson has a great solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/stopping-a-macro-using-button-while-macro-is/6e800e52-1619-4d3b-928e-f554c2a94f72) that I believe solves your problem.  I'll explain it in a nutshell in case the link is ever broken.  This would go in your code and on the sheet in question you would create a command button and assign another sub that would set `StopCode` to `True`.  When user clicks the button, `StopCode` would be set to `True`, code stops running.

```
StopCode = False
Do Until StopCode = True
    DoEvents
    ' your code here. next line is just an example
```

Comment: I already have a pop up window that informs the user how to stop the script if it takes too long. If we could add a "stop" button to it, that would be great! I will start to study the script asap!

Comment: so the first problem I met, is talking between subs. I have the main sub that does the hard job, I inserted the code there. How do I make the variable editable in another sub?

Comment: make the variable editable globally by declaring it outside of any specific sub. So put 'Dim StopCode As Boolean' before both subs.

Comment: It only works if I put it to the top of the module. If I put it to the top of the main module, it simply does not work. If I put it to the code of the userform too, Excel crashes

Comment: So I had to put `Option Explicit` before the global bool, now the Excel does not crash, but it still does not work.

Comment: Did you examine the example code in the link provided?

Comment: yes, I have. But I still do not get it, how to set the boolean true in the module **from** the userform